# How to get images from hidden folder in android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am able to fetch all the images from any specified non hidden folder from device but how can I get all the images from a hidden specified folder. 
As soon as I mention my hidden folder name in the query, cursor return null

```
  public static List<MediaData> getAppScannedImages(Context context) {
    Cursor imagecursor = null;
    List<MediaData> gallerydata = new ArrayList<MediaData>();

    try {
        final String orderBy = Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";
        imagecursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projectionImage,
                        Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + "='"
                                + ".myHiddenFolder" + "'", null,
                        orderBy);
        if (imagecursor != null) {
            imagecursor.moveToFirst();
            int count = imagecursor.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                MediaData galData = new MediaData();
                galData.setKey_id(i);
                galData.setId(imagecursor.getString(0));
                galData.setName(imagecursor.getString(1));
                galData.setPath(imagecursor.getString(2));
                galData.setDate(imagecursor.getString(3));
                gallerydata.add(galData);
                imagecursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (imagecursor != null) {
            imagecursor.close();
        }
    }
    return gallerydata;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the code? If yes then does it resolve your issue? tell me if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach.
You have to find out the list of hidden folder from sd card and search all those folders for images.

the follwoing code is displays hidden files:

```
public void goTODir(File dir) {

//dir is initail dir like="/mnt/sdcard"
    String imageType = ".jpg";

    File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                goTODir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
              if (listFile[i].isHidden()){
                        if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(imageType))
                            {
                              //add to your array list
                               }


              }
            }
        }
    }    
 }
```

Comment: I don't have to query all the hidden folders for images but only one specific folder lets say ".myHiddenFolder" in above case. The folder is created by application only and contains images only.

Comment: you have to specify that path in this variable then, for e.g. dir="/mnt/sdcard/myHiddenFolder"

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File dir = new File(path);
          File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
          for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
              if(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath().contains("your hidden folder name")){                
                  File dirtest = new File(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath()); 
                  File listFiletest[] = dirtest.listFiles();
                  for (int j = 0; j < listFiletest.length; j++) {
                     get all images from hidden folder
                  }
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin Lover**

```
   companion object {
    const val FOLDER_PATH = "/YourFolder/.hideen/"
}

/**
 * Method to get all Image Path
 * @return [ArrayList]
 * */
fun getImagePath(): ArrayList<String> {

    // image path list
    val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    // fetching file path from storage
    val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + FOLDER_PATH)
    val listFile = file.listFiles()

    if (listFile != null && listFile.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Arrays.sort(listFile, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE)
    }

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (imgFile in listFile) {
            if (
                imgFile.name.endsWith(".jpg")
                || imgFile.name.endsWith(".jpeg")
                || imgFile.name.endsWith(".png")
            ) {
                val model : String = imgFile.absolutePath
                list.add(model)
            }
        }
    }

    // return imgPath List
    return list
}
```